# Laravel remember cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm trying to remember cache for 6 minute on home page but it's errors.
I want 10 parameters in one key ( homepage-data )
so what i'm doing wrong?

```
public function index()
{
    $rememberKey = 'homepage-data';
    $minutes = 600;
    \Cache::remember($rememberKey, $minutes, function () {

        $breakingNews = BreakingNews::published();
        $rightSlider = Article::rightSlider()->take(20)->get();
        $leftSlider = Article::leftSlider()->take(9)->get();
        $shows = Show::publishedOrderShows()->take(10)->get();
        $blogs = Article::allBlogs()->take(12)->get();
        $latestNews = Article::latestNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id')))->take(5)->get();
        $otherNews = Article::otherNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id')))->take(2)->get();
        $otherNewsDown = Article::otherNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id'))->merge($otherNews->pluck('id')))->take(8)->get();
        $analyticNews = Article::allAnalytics()->take(4)->get();
        $populars = Article::popular()->take(10)->get();
        $quizzes = Quizze::quizOrderBy();

        return view('pages/home-page')->with([
            'breakingNews' => $breakingNews, 'rightSlider' => $rightSlider,
            'leftSlider' => $leftSlider, 'shows' => $shows, 'blogs' => $blogs, 'latestNews' => $latestNews,
            'otherNews' => $otherNews, 'otherNewsDown' => $otherNewsDown, 'analyticNews' => $analyticNews,
            'populars' => $populars, 'quizzes' => $quizzes
        ]);
    });
}
```

I'm getting Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed error.

Comment: What errors does it give?

Comment: You're defeating the purpose of the cache. It will run all of those queries on each request instead of retrieving them from the cache. Instead, the queries should be inside of the cache. Read up on [Laravel caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache) to see how it works, specifically [Retrieve & Store](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#retrieve-store)

Comment: I edited code  but i'm getting ' Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed error. ' error

Comment: `view` returns a request unless you use `->__toString()`, so that won't work. Of course, you're not returning anything out of the function itself now.

Comment: it's working   $rememberKey = 'homepage-data';
        $minutes = 600;
        $rightSlider = \Cache::remember($rememberKey, $minutes, function () {
            return Article::rightSlider()->take(20)->get();
        });         but i need all variables not only one okey thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original question, you were defeating the purpose of the cache by having all of your queries outside of the cache. Now, you have too much inside of your closure, and it's trying to serialize the view. Move the view outside of the cache, assign the retrieved cache to `$data`, then use that as an array to send back to the view.

```
public function index()
{
   
    $rememberKey = 'homepage-data';
    $minutes = 600;
    $data = \Cache::remember($rememberKey, $minutes, function ()  {
        $breakingNews = BreakingNews::published();
        $rightSlider = Article::rightSlider()->take(20)->get();
        $leftSlider = Article::leftSlider()->take(9)->get();
        $shows = Show::publishedOrderShows()->take(10)->get();
        $blogs = Article::allBlogs()->take(12)->get();
        $latestNews = Article::latestNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id')))->take(5)->get();
        $otherNews = Article::otherNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id')))->take(2)->get();
        $otherNewsDown = Article::otherNews()->whereNotIn('id', $rightSlider->pluck('id')->merge($leftSlider->pluck('id'))->merge($otherNews->pluck('id')))->take(8)->get();
        $analyticNews = Article::allAnalytics()->take(4)->get();
        $populars = Article::popular()->take(10)->get();
        $quizzes = Quizze::quizOrderBy();

        // CACHE
        return ['breakingNews' => $breakingNews, 
           'rightSlider'=>  $rightSlider, 
            'leftSlider' => $leftSlider, 
            'shows' => $shows, 
            'blogs' => $blogs, 
            'latestNews' => $latestNews, 
            'otherNews' => $otherNews, 
            'otherNewsDown' => $otherNewsDown, 
            'analyticNews' => $analyticNews,
            'populars' => $populars,
            'quizzes' => $quizzes];
       
    });

    return view('pages/home-page')->with([
        'breakingNews' => $data['breakingNews'], 'rightSlider' => $data['rightSlider'],
        'leftSlider' => $data['leftSlider'], 'shows' => $data['shows'], 'blogs' => $data['blogs'], 'latestNews' => $data['latestNews'],
        'otherNews' => $data['otherNews'], 'otherNewsDown' => $data['otherNewsDown'], 'analyticNews' => $data['analyticNews'],
        'populars' => $data['populars'], 'quizzes' => $data['quizzes']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting Serialization of 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection' is not allowed error.

Comment: All but `$quizzes` and `$breakingNews` have `get()` on them, so it's probably one of those two lines.

Comment: Yes but they have get in model

Comment: You're going to have to do some troubleshooting to figure out which one it is. Remove the queries one by one, replacing them with dummy data, to figure out which one is causing the error.

Comment: Yep i'm trying now but its on 66 line where is this  "     });    "  on return view TOP  is it passable that it is closed wrong ?

Comment: No, that's the proper closing tags for the code.

Comment: Okay i will search thanks for help guys